# Couldn't insert the image in to database using java mysqli

Tags: java, mysql

I am creating simple payroll system in java. I could browse the image and set the label correctly after that I am going to insert the image in to the database I couldn't insert. I don't how to insert image into the database. I am beginner of java. What I tried so far I attached below.

[image]

**Browse the image**

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try
    {          
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();           
        if(fc.showOpenDialog(fc) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(fc.getSelectedFile());
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(new 
        ImageIcon(img).getImage().getScaledInstance(250, 250, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        imagelabel.setIcon(imageIcon);      
    }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(emploee.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }     
    }
```

**Save the data in to Database**

```
 try {                                   
             String firstname = txtfirstname.getText();
             String lastname = txtlastname.getText();         
             String Gender;           
             if(jRadioButton1.isSelected())
             {
                 Gender = "Male";
             }
             else
             {
                 Gender = "Female";
             }            
             String address = txtaddress.getText();           
             String batch = txtbsal.getText();                 
             FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(img);

             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");            
             con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/empay","root","");                
             pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into records(firstname,lastname,gender,address,bsal,photo)values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");            
             pst.setString(1, firstname);
             pst.setString(2, lastname);                  
             pst.setString(3, Gender);
             pst.setString(4, address);   
             pst.setString(5, batch);                  
             pst.setBinaryStream(6,(InputStream)fin,(int)img.length());                        
                 pst.executeUpdate();
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registation Created...........");  

         } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(emploee.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         } catch (SQLException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(emploee.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
```

**This is the code which i used to browse image :**

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();           
            if(fc.showOpenDialog(fc) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(fc.getSelectedFile());
            ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(new 
            ImageIcon(img).getImage().getScaledInstance(250, 250, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
            imagelabel.setIcon(imageIcon);
```

Get the image and put the img object. This img object I'm going to insert in to database:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(fc.getSelectedFile());
```

Insert the image in to the database:

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(img);
pst.setBinaryStream(6,(InputStream)fin,(int)img.length());
```

Error displayed cannot find the symbol:

Error image:

[image]

Comment: Isnt mysqli in PHP?

Comment: Any errors or anything else?

Comment: error show there  FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(img); img error

Comment: how to insert the image into the database in java sir.

Comment: How about attaching actual error instead of claiming it is just there sir?

Comment: What exactly is `img` in the second code snippet? And please [edit] your code and show us the complete stack trace of the error.

Comment: i have update the above error

Comment: You haven't share the table details, nor the actual error. Do these and then we can help. `error displayed cannot find the symbol` isn't that a compilation error?

Comment: Where is that error again?

Comment: i attached the image above of error. how to save the image in to database

Comment: And what is `img`? Not a file obviously. Or what is worst - it is not declared.

Comment: BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(fc.getSelectedFile()); this line in the browse image

Comment: First, it should be input stream, second - no it is not because "cannot find symbol" says so.

Comment: That variable you have mentioned is scoped to try-catch block it is declared in. You need to read about scopes of variables.

Comment: can you write full code sir for save the image in to the database

Comment: No i cannot, sir.

Comment: can you resolve my problem code which i wrote above

Comment: Yes, and that requires you to understand variable scopes first.

Comment: ok sirrrrrrrr.............